# SSH KEY: sudo git clone permission denied

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I created a public ssh key into my pc (ubuntu 16.04), and linked it with my gitlab.com account.
I used `$ sudo git clone git@gitlab.com:XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git` and I had this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

So What I did: I added 777 chmod to my html folder and used only the command `$ git clone git@gitlab.com:XXXXXX/XXXXXX.git` and the clone was created successfully.

Can someone explain me what just happen??

Comment: Since you were running `git` as root, presumably it tried to log in with root's ssh keys (if any), not yours.

Comment: I didn't think to that, can you add this as an answer, so we can close this topic? Thank you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you were running `git` as root, presumably it tried to log in with root's ssh keys (if any), not yours.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on GitLab. I read GitHub's document about ssh key (generating, adding and etc) and I could do it successfully.

[GitHub document guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/)